# Admob User Requirements per Day?

Tags: android, admob

I have a few apps still not uploaded to **Google Play Store**, I want to upload my apps to another **Store** rather than Play Store until I create a **Play Console Account**.

When I upload my app to Galaxy Store or Amazon or any other supported store, is there any user requirements for per day, week or month in **Google AdMob**, For example: **'My App need to have 500 users or(impressions) per day'**.

Thanks,

Comment: Why do you think such requirement could exist?

Comment: Aren't there such requirements?

Comment: I am asking you

Answer (score 0):

I got all these details, Google AdMob don't have such policy.

The important thing is a supported store needed to be uploaded.

Here is a link for this answer:
https://support.google.com/admob/thread/175480084?hl=en&msgid=175480275#